# Update MVC4 website using FTP, Server doesn't "rebuild"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm brand new to MVC and coming from ASPX 3.5 websites.  With ASPX I always just copied files via FTP/SFTP/RDP from my test PC to my production server, to update pages.  Next time the page was requested, the new version would be used.  Is it not this simple with MVC 4?

Even on my local copy I have to do a "rebuild" and/or "run" the project again anytime I update files in Visual Studio 2012.  With ASPX all I had to do was save the file and then reload the page in my already open browser (as long as Casini or my local IIS was still running).  Views I'm able to update without doing a rebuild, but not Controllers.

How do I get my server to "rebuild" if this is what I need to do, or do I need to always copy files from some obj/bin folder to update the server?  I copied the entire folder over to my server and it is working, but then I added a new Controller and View, and the URL is giving a 401 error like it does when the Controller doesn't exist.  Works fine on my local copy, so I assume it is a cache/rebuild issue.

Seems like a step backwards... although I'm guessing there is a performance reason, if it has to be this way.

Edit: In case it matters, my server is IIS6, Windows 2003, 64-bit OS running IIS in 32-bit mode.

Comment: Have you tried forcing the app to recycle? Change the web.config (add a space somewhere non-important and save the file).  Whereas pages (.aspx) are static, controllers are determined at app startup based on naming conventions.  If you add a controller after the app is started, you may need to recycle the app.  This can also be done in IIS with the restart button.

Comment: I did try a recycle for the process that is used for this site (I have a separate process for my 2 .NET 4.0 sites, since most are 3.5) and that didn't work.  I did end up finding a Cooking.dll (Cooking is the name of my project) in the bin folder, and once I copied that to the site, it updated/rebuilt.  So maybe I just need to copy that file every time... kind of a pain to copy an extra file though, so still hoping for another way, but one that doesn't require me to change everything I do/know (I like FTP).

Comment: sounds like a default setting on the project template was screwed up.  For non-compiled items, for example a css file, you can right-click the file and choose 'properties.'  From there, you can set the 'Copy to Output Directory' value to 'copy always.'  I'll have to do some more research to see if this can also be the case for an assembly.

Comment: I don't think anything was screwed up but me not knowing/thinking I'd have to copy files from the bin folder for the type of changes I had made (just views and controller files).  I guess that is new to MVC, and I was used to only looking for updated bin files if some library I was using was updated... not my own code, from the website I was updating.  I know in classic ASP.NET there was an option to pre-compile your site to a DLL, but I never used that.  Sounds like now it always works that way, or at least parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think anything was screwed up but me not knowing/thinking I'd have to copy files from the bin folder for the type of changes I had made (just views and controller files). I guess that is new to MVC, and I was used to only looking for updated bin files if some library I was using was updated... not my own code, from the website I was updating. I know in classic ASP.NET there was an option to pre-compile your site to a DLL, but I never used that. Sounds like now it always works that way, or at least parts.

Answer (score -1):

I'd highly recommend using the WebDeploy tool do publishing. You need to install it on the target server, but once it's set up it make publishing a real pleasure. 
http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy

Don't be put off by all the talk about web farms, it works great for single servers in uncomplicated environments too.

Also look into web.config transforms, for editing your web.config file as you publish your site. This might be to change the Database or SMTP server that you use in production compared to Dev. 
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WebDeploymentMadeAwesomeIfYoureUsingXCopyYoureDoingItWrong.aspx

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted, and it does seem odd... does this maybe not work well with IIS6?  I do see that some of the features that look important/good are for IIS7, so not sure if I should look in to this just yet.